# IllegalStateException java httpclient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, illegalstateexception

I am trying to retrieve a text file from the internet using the apache httpclient. I am using the following code:

```
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet getHNMR = new HttpGet("http://www.hmdb.ca/labm/metabolites/" + HMDB + "/chemical/pred_hnmr_peaklist/" + HMDB + "_peaks.txt");
        HttpGet getCNMR = new HttpGet("http://www.hmdb.ca/labm/metabolites/" + HMDB + "/chemical/pred_cnmr_peaklist/" + HMDB + "_peaks.txt");

        try {
            responseH = httpclient.execute(getHNMR);
            responseC = httpclient.execute(getCNMR);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("client exception");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("ioexception");
        }
        //Generate HNMR peak list
        HttpEntity entityH = responseH.getEntity();
        HttpEntity entityC = responseH.getEntity();;
        try {
            HNMR = EntityUtils.toString(entityH);
            CNMR = EntityUtils.toString(entityC);
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("parseexception");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("ioexception");
        }
    //Set peak lists to textarea
        HC.setText(CNMR + "\n" + HNMR);
```

I am getting the following stack trace:

```
Thread [pool-2-thread-1] (Suspended (exception IllegalStateException))  
ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) line: 1128  
ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: 603   
Thread.run() line: 679
```

I'm not that familiar with debugging, so I'm not sure what's exactly happening.

Comment: Did you try to download the files sequentially? I am not sure, whether the HttpClient actually supports this interleaved kind of operation shown in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response body must be consumed *before* the connection can be used for another request. You should read the response InputStream fully prior to the next HTTP execute. Your code should be appear in the following order:

```
    responseH = httpclient.execute(getHNMR);
    HttpEntity entityH = responseH.getEntity();
    HNMR = EntityUtils.toString(entityH);

    responseC = httpclient.execute(getCNMR);
    HttpEntity entityC = responseC.getEntity();
    CNMR = EntityUtils.toString(entityC);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it a requirement that you use httpClient? Given that it is only a text file and you don't need any post or get parameters, a simpler method would be:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.hmdb.ca/labm/metabolites/" + HMDB + "/chemical/pred_hnmr_peaklist/" + HMDB + "_peaks.txt");
InputStream response = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
```